# Manually assign tasks to a machine

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am very new to Hadoop and working on developing a custom scheduler based on given algorithm/policy.

Hence, I want to know how to manually/programmatically assign map/reduce task to a specific machine on Hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible unless you just using Hadoop in psuedo distributed mode.

Think of it, why would you do it? If you start to specify machine name where you want to run map/red, and if that machine goes down? Also what if you selected machine that's on separate data center by mistake?

So i don't find any advantage of specifying machine for where to run map/reduce. Let framework take care of which machine it needs to run map/red on.

Answer (score 0):

You would not be able to specify a mapper to execute on.